# Getting a count by date based on the number of observations with encompassing date ranges

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, join

I am working with a table in Microsoft Access whereby I have 2 columns with a start and end date.

I want to get the count by date of the number of rows with date ranges that encompass the date in the output table.

**Input Data**

```
Start Date  End Date
01/02/2017  03/02/2017
07/02/2017  19/02/2017
09/02/2017  19/02/2017
11/02/2017  12/02/2017
12/02/2017  17/02/2017
```

**Desired Output**

```
Date    Count
01/02/2017  1
02/02/2017  1
03/02/2017  1
04/02/2017  0
05/02/2017  0
06/02/2017  0
07/02/2017  1
08/02/2017  1
09/02/2017  2
10/02/2017  2
11/02/2017  3
12/02/2017  4
13/02/2017  3
14/02/2017  3
15/02/2017  3
16/02/2017  3
17/02/2017  3
18/02/2017  2
19/02/2017  2
20/02/2017  0
```

For this project, I have to use Microsoft Access 2010, so a solution in either SQL code or design view input would be great.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are many questions that explain how to get date ranges in SQL. What have you tried? Currently, this is a *"please program this for me, I searched for a few minutes but found nothing I could copy and paste"* question, and those are frowned upon here.

Comment: I did not find any post on here that summed by an encompassing date range criteria. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below query to get the required result. You can also change the column with respect to your requirements

```
SELECT END_DATE AS DATE, COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY END_DATE ORDER BY END_DATE;
```

Comment: Eh ... that will return four (4) values only, with a count between 1 and 2. So "worked"?